# How to allow Chrome to handle PDF only for specific domains?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, viewer

I never liked Chrome's PDF handling and always had it disabled => download the PDF instead, and let me open it with Adobe. Recently I started working with an accounting website (holded.com) to which I upload numerous PDF files, like invoices etc. Alas, these files cannot be viewed in the website as long as Chrome is not set to "open PDFs in Chrome".
I wonder if there was a way to tell Chrome to handle PDF files *ONLY* under specific websites and domains, so that the default behavior is "download", but "open" for the registered sites.
Anyone has an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

According to my Experience Google Chrome does not allow to handle PDF based on Domain if you set PDF document Behavior as "Download PDFs" it will apply for every site you cant exclude specific domain
[image]